# Unity error after adding skybox material

Tags: unity

So I added the night material from the fantasy skybox asset I download from the asset store and the rest of my objects turned white for some reason I figured it was just a glitch like the light baking and it would be okay when I deployed my project

Well I saved and built my project as usual and the objects all turn pink as if their materials did not exist and every time I go to play the game I receive the following error

'Assets/Build/ParcoreBeast_Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll' shouldn't be queried by IsAssemblyCompatible, missing IsInternalOrCompiledAssembly check ?
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:GetMonoIslands()
UnityEditor.SyncVS:SyncVisualStudioProjectIfItAlreadyExists()

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you create a build of your project and save that build in your assets. If you move the build from the assets then the error should go away.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting Library file might solve the problem

Comment: We like to see chunky answers. Could you describe why the issue happens and how it's related to the solution suggest?